# Retrieving metadata from x264?

Tags: h.264, x264

I am trying to exctract the meta data from x264-encoded video files. First priority is to map the IDR-frames structure. The work seams to be harder than expected and I am trying to find command line applications that I can control from my code.

Mp4box has an option "-dump-xml" or similar but I can't figure out how it works. Not much help available on the net on this option.

Anyone who can give me a hint on this or any other alternative?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something that calls `mpeg4ip`. This application contains `mp4dump, avidump, yuvdump...`.

Check it out here: http://mpeg4ip.sourceforge.net/documentation/index.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use [MediaInfo](http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net/) It's a CLI software and can get the metainfo about videos and export them into an HTML or XML file; of course, it supports MP4. It's available for Linux (deb families and rpm ones), Mac OSX, Windows, BSD, etc.

You could use a command like this:

```
mediainfo --Output=XML video.mp4 > file.xml
```

This will output the metainfo of video.mp4 to file.xml
Metainfo included in the file includes format, codec, file size, duration, bit rate, frame rate, width, height, color space, stream size among others.

I hope this answer has been helful ;) =)